# Message security verification failed.Cannot read KeyIdentifierClause from element 'KeyIdentifier'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, interop

Here is the complete error message:

> Message security verification failed.
>   
> Cannot read KeyIdentifierClause from element 'KeyIdentifier' with namespace
>   
> 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'.
>   
> Custom KeyIdentifierClauses require custom SecurityTokenSerializers,
>  please refer to the SDK for examples

**Here is the story:** We are trying to implement a WCF client which talks to a non-WCF web service and most likely the web service has been implemented on J2EE platform. The message sent out from WCF client has to be signed. Fortunately, we were able to find a post at stackoverflow and were able to follow the guidelines / tips in that post. Below is the custom binding:

```html
<customBinding>
    <binding name="AccountServiceSoap11Binding1" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
        <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
        </security>
        <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

We were able to send the request and server responds nicely (we could see the response using fiddler2). Everything works except for the above exception occurred. We did search and found out couple suggestions or clues listed below:

**One: sceanairo#12: Incorrect version of security header**

[blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2011/03/07/wcf-security-interop-scenarios.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2011/03/07/wcf-security-interop-scenarios.aspx)

**Two: ask vendor to make some changes**

[social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0732bb4d-7dbb-4b43-8821-3f0caba600eb/cannot-read-keyidentifierclause-from-element-x509issuerserial-with-namespace?forum=wcf](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0732bb4d-7dbb-4b43-8821-3f0caba600eb/cannot-read-keyidentifierclause-from-element-x509issuerserial-with-namespace?forum=wcf)

Please advise what we could do to avoid the exception.

Many thanks,

Peter